# SurfaceCheckBox default template

Tags: wpf, pixelsense

Can somebody please extract a default template of a `SurfaceCheckBox` for me? I have tried using Blend 2 but failed miserably. The extracted template has some unresolved `TargetName` references.

I am trying to change the template so that the check mark is top aligned. It is centered vertically by default and there doesn't seem to be a direct way to change it.

[Edit] I have also tried Blend 3 which was a bit better but I am still missing "Glow" target and many references to it. This renders the template unusable unless all "Glow" references are removed. If I do that I get a working template but with no glow.

Comment: Useless answer.. deleted it. I tried all the other controls from the SurfaceToolkit, they all miss "Glow"

Comment: Updated my answer, it worked once I added the reference to Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Blend 4. Working this time, apperently you had to add a reference to Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic.dll and then add

```
xmlns:Microsoft_Surface_Presentation_Generic="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic;assembly=Microsoft.Surface.Presentation.Generic"
```

before you would get the Glow part when editing a style.

```
<!-- SimpleButtonFocusVisual is used to show keyboard focus around a SimpleButton control -->
<Style x:Key="SurfaceButtonFocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <!-- nothing, we don't want to make difference whether the element has focus or not-->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Common Brushes -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NormalForegroundBrush"
    Color="#FF000000" />

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="Default_FillBrush"
    Color="#33A4B4BD"/>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="EdgeBrush"
    EndPoint="0,1"
    StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#7FFFFFFF"
        Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#0CFFFFFF"
        Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!-- Disabled Brushes are used for the Disabled look of each control -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledRenderBrush"
    Color="#0CFFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledEdgeBrush"
    Color="#33FFFFFF"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBevelBorder"
    Color="#33000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledForegroundBrush"
    Color="#A5333333"/>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ShadowBorderBrush"
    Color="#33000000"/>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="BevelBorderBrush"
    EndPoint="0,0"
    StartPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#66000000"
        Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#33000000"
        Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="RenderBrush"
    EndPoint="0,0"
    StartPoint="0,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#26000000"
        Offset="0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#4CFFFFFF"
        Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!--Color for Glow-->
<Color x:Key="GlowColor">#FFFFFFFF</Color>

<!-- ButtonBase -->
<Style x:Key="SurfaceButtonStyle"
    TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
        Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
        Value="{StaticResource SurfaceButtonFocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
        Value="Segoe UI" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
        Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
        Value="{StaticResource NormalForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
        Value="{StaticResource Default_FillBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
        Value="{StaticResource EdgeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
        Value="1,1,1,1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
        Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
        Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
        Value="15,6,15,6" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
        Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
        Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="MinWidth"
        Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight"
        Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Press">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Glow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                Value="1" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Glow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                Value="-3,-3,-3,-3" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Release">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Glow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000"
                                Value="1" />
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.5,0.5,0.5,1"
                                KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000"
                                Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Glow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000"
                                Value="-3,-3,-3,-3" />
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeySpline="0.5,0.5,0.5,1"
                                KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000"
                                Value="1,1,1,1" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <Grid x:Name="Grid"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                    <Border Margin="1,1,1,0"
                        x:Name="Shadow"
                        BorderThickness="0,0,0,1"
                        CornerRadius="6,6,6,6"
                        Padding="1,1,1,1"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource ShadowBorderBrush}" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="Base"
                        Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        Stroke="{StaticResource BevelBorderBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="1"
                        RadiusX="5"
                        RadiusY="5"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        Margin="1,1,1,1" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="RenderOverlay"
                        Opacity="1"
                        Fill="{StaticResource RenderBrush}"
                        Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        StrokeThickness="1"
                        RadiusX="4"
                        RadiusY="4"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                        Margin="2,2,2,2" />
                    <Microsoft_Surface_Presentation_Generic:SurfaceShadowChrome Margin="1,1,1,1"
                        x:Name="Glow"
                        Color="{StaticResource GlowColor}"
                        CornerRadius="4,4,4,4"
                        Opacity="0" />
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Content"
                        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        <ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                            <TranslateTransform X="0"
                                Y="-1" />
                        </ContentPresenter.RenderTransform>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                        Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Press}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Release}" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="True" />
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledRenderBrush}"
                            TargetName="RenderOverlay" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledEdgeBrush}"
                            TargetName="RenderOverlay" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledBevelBorder}"
                            TargetName="Base" />
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            Value="#00000000"
                            TargetName="Shadow" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                            Value="#00FFFFFF" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBackgroundBrush"
    Color="#00000000"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="DisabledBorderBrush"
    Color="#33000000"/>

<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="CheckBox_RenderOverlayBrush"
    GradientOrigin="0.627,0.5">
    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5"
                CenterY="0.5"
                ScaleX="-2.056"
                ScaleY="-4.033"/>
            <SkewTransform AngleX="0"
                AngleY="0"
                CenterX="0.5"
                CenterY="0.5"/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90.17"
                CenterX="0.5"
                CenterY="0.5"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="-0.016"
                Y="-0.429"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
    <GradientStop Color="#19000000"
        Offset="0.205"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#0CFFFFFF"
        Offset="0.652"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>

<!--CheckBox Brushes-->
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckmarkIconGradientBrush"
    EndPoint="0.5,0"
    StartPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF292929"
        Offset="0.5"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF1B1B1B"
        Offset="0.196"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<!-- CheckBox -->
<Style x:Key="SurfaceCheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type my:SurfaceCheckBox}"
    BasedOn="{StaticResource SurfaceButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
        Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
        Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
        Value="{StaticResource NormalForegroundBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
        Value="5,0,0,0" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type my:SurfaceCheckBox}">
                <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Press">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Glow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                Value="1" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Glow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                Value="-3,-3,-3,-3" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Release">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Glow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000"
                                Value="1" />
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeySpline="0.5,0.5,0.5,1"
                                KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000"
                                Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Glow"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Margin)">
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.0000000"
                                Value="-3,-3,-3,-3" />
                            <SplineThicknessKeyFrame KeySpline="0.5,0.5,0.5,1"
                                KeyTime="00:00:00.5000000"
                                Value="1,1,1,1" />
                        </ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Unchecked">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.2000000"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Checkmark"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            To="0" />
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="Checked">
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.2000000"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="Checkmark"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                            To="1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="ThreeStateEnter">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ThreeStateMark"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.1000000"
                                Value="0.9" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Key="ThreeStateExit">
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                            Storyboard.TargetName="ThreeStateMark"
                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.2000000"
                                Value="0" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                <BulletDecorator MinHeight="30"
                    MinWidth="30"
                    Height="Auto"
                    Background="Transparent"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                    x:Name="bulletDecorator">
                    <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <Grid MinHeight="30"
                            MinWidth="30"
                            Width="30"
                            Height="30"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Base"
                                Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Stroke="Transparent"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                RadiusX="7"
                                RadiusY="7"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                Margin="2,2,2,2" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Button"
                                Fill="{StaticResource Default_FillBrush}"
                                Stroke="{StaticResource BevelBorderBrush}"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                RadiusX="7"
                                RadiusY="7"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                Margin="2,2,2,2" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="RenderOverlay"
                                Fill="{StaticResource CheckBox_RenderOverlayBrush}"
                                Stroke="{StaticResource EdgeBrush}"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                RadiusX="6"
                                RadiusY="6"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                Margin="3,3,3,3" />
                            <Microsoft_Surface_Presentation_Generic:SurfaceShadowChrome CornerRadius="6,6,6,6"
                                x:Name="Glow"
                                Color="{StaticResource GlowColor}"
                                Opacity="0"
                                Margin="-1,-1,-1,-1" />
                            <Path x:Name="Checkmark"
                                StrokeEndLineCap="Flat"
                                Fill="{x:Null}"
                                Stroke="{StaticResource CheckmarkIconGradientBrush}"
                                StrokeStartLineCap="Flat"
                                StrokeThickness="4"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Height="Auto"
                                Data="M4.2195036,10.149215 L9.4262573,13.556164 17.449568,5.9264725 17.449648,6.780637 9.3715682,13.987686 4.2190426,11.048134 z"
                                Opacity="0"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                Margin="7.96,11.023,7.999,8.187"
                                Stretch="Fill" />
                            <Rectangle x:Name="ThreeStateMark"
                                Opacity="0"
                                Fill="{StaticResource CheckmarkIconGradientBrush}"
                                Stroke="{StaticResource BevelBorderBrush}"
                                StrokeThickness="1"
                                RadiusX="4"
                                RadiusY="4"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                Margin="6,6,6,6" />

                        </Grid>
                    </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                    <Grid Margin="5,0,0,0"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        <Grid Background="Transparent"
                            x:Name="ContentBox"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                x:Name="Content"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </BulletDecorator>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ThreeStateEnter}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ThreeStateExit}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsThreeState"
                                Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                                Value="{x:Null}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                        Value="False">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Unchecked}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Checked}" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                        Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Checked}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Unchecked}" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                        Value="True">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Press}" />
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource Release}" />
                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                        Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                            TargetName="Button"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                            TargetName="Button"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />

                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Fill"
                            TargetName="RenderOverlay"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledBackgroundBrush}" />

                        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                            TargetName="Checkmark"
                            Value="{StaticResource DisabledBorderBrush}" />
                        <Setter Property="Opacity"
                            TargetName="RenderOverlay"
                            Value="0.5" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks! Your Blend 4 template seems to be missing "Glow" target as well. What's up with that? Why isn't it generated?

Comment: Haha, yeah.. Getting half a template because you're missing a reference seems less than ideal :)